# Mysql query create a view with join and distinct

Tags: mysql, view, distinct

i need some helps with a query that i can create correctly for what i want.

i'm explaining all:

accounts ( id, name, surname,email, telephone ..) with id p.k.
boc (ad,username, port..) with ad p.k   .

Telephone and Username have the same values in their tables

i need to create a view that's report all fields are into table accounts and table bow and that have as ports 16 and 17.

My query is:

```
CREATE VIEW exportable 
AS
(SELECT A.ID,A.NOME,A.SURNAME,A.EMAIL,A.TELEPHONE,B.AD,B.USERNAME,B.PORT
  FROM ACCOUNTS A, BOC B
 WHERE A.TELEPHONE = B.USERNAME AND B.PORT= 16 AND 17);
```

this query works in a good way, i have all field and row are completed, but obv this kind of query doesn't exclude some copies row, that i need to exclude. Can someone give me a suggestion ?

Thank you.
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first think i notice is that you you should use JOIN instead of this all fashion way of joining table... Your query may look like this than

```
SELECT A.ID,A.NOME,A.SURNAME,A.EMAIL,A.TELEPHONE,B.AD,B.USERNAME,B.PORT
FROM ACCOUNTS A
INNER JOIN BOC B
ON A.TELEPHONE = B.USERNAME 
WHERE B.PORT = 16 OR B.PORT = 17
```

I understand that B.PORT should be 16 OR 17 I'm not quiet sure how your table data looks like...

GL!

Comment: thank you for you great help that has clarify my doubt, i have solved all things with this query


CREATE VIEW EXPORTABLE AS

SELECT DISTINCT A.ID,A.NOME,A.SURNAME,A.EMAIL,A.TELEPHONE,B.AD,B.USERNAME,B.PORT
FROM ACCOUNTS AS A
INNER JOIN BOC AS B
ON A.TELEPHONE = B.USERNAME 
WHERE B.PORT = 16 OR B.PORT = 17;

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad to hear that you solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your "where" statement to exclude some rows:

```
and A.id not in (12, 13, 14)
```

where 12, 13 and 14 are the exception id's.